# Is there a way to know inside angularJS service which directive called that service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

What I mean is - I have a directive that is being duplicate on the same page. Lets say it is a grid. I have 3 grids on the same page. Now, each one of the grid is firing event called "Foo" but I want to know which of the grids really fired that event. How can I know that? Is there an id to each of the same directive child's?

Comment: Store the information in the fired event?

Answer (score 0):

If you're broadcasting a DOM event then you can use `Event.target`to get the element the event was triggered from and from that you can use `angular.element(Event.target).scope()` to get the scope of the triggered element. If the triggered element isn't the grid itself but a child of the grid (likely) then you'll need to use jqLite or jQuery to find the grid from the target.

If you're not broadcasting a DOM event, then use your own event object that provides a target property.